# Issue with setBackground(): the drawable seems to be applied to the parent, not to the view

Tags: android, setbackground

I have developed a custom view that extends the `View` class:

```
public class ScRectangle extends View implements Parcelable{ ... }
```

I also have created the following Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<corners
    android:radius="@dimen/thickBorder" />
<stroke android:width="@dimen/thickBorder"
    android:color="@color/fab_color_normal" />
```

I then try to apply this drawable as background to a new instance of the above custom view:

```
    ScRectangle r = new ScRectangle(this, left, top, right, bottom, "thinBorder", "OrangeState", 0);
    r.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.selected_state));
    drawingFrame.addView(r);
```

`r` is the only view in `drawingFrame`. The above code correctly adds the expected rectangle inside the frame, on the correct location and with the correct size. However, the drawable seems to be applied to `drawingFrame` instead of to `r`.

***** EDIT *****

In the picture below, `r` is the small light-orange square in D5, while the drawable is the dark-orange border along the whole grid.

[image]

How should change the above code?

Comment: Can you post a picture of that?

Comment: You're adding your custom `View` with no `LayoutParams` specified, so it's probably filling the parent. The fact that you have `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` arguments in your `View`'s constructor call makes me think that those are the bounds for your rectangle. However, the background set on that `View` is going to fill the `View`'s bounds, not your rectangle's bounds, so it appears that it's being set on the parent, when in fact, your custom `View` is just filling the parent. You need to handle drawing that image yourself, and/or use appropriate `LayoutParams` when adding the `View`.

Comment: left, top, right, bottom are wrong. And whenever add a view to ViewGroup speicfy it's LayoutParams. And get left,top,etc from those params

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you Mike. Using `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` I set margins for the parent and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Override

setBackground method in your custom class and set background to current view

Comment: in the onDraw() method of the custom class?

Comment: can you add the layout file ?